# Select rows depending on field value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have 2 tables: Employee and Appointments.

1 Employee can have multiple Appointments. 
There is a field: Visibility which can hold 0, 1 or 2.

```
  0: show any of the appointment, 
  1: Show this appointment only, 
  2: Don't show the appointment.
```

Now i want to select the records of employee and appointments:

1. if visibility is 1 then select that record and not any other records
2. if visibility is 0 then select just a record, like the top 1
3. if visibility is 2 then select nulls for that record, except the employee id.

can anyone point me out how it can be done using Sql Server 2000?

Comment: 2000 as in the question text or 2005 as in the tag? What if an Employee has 2 Appointments with the `visibility` flag set to `1`? TBH I don't really understand the structure you have.

Comment: "like the top 1" - what defines the top? the earliest or latest by a date? the one with the greatest id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm making a couple of assumptions.

1. Its possible to have more than one appointment
2. If you have an appointments with 1 and 0 you want to Guarantee the one with 1 is shown
3. You can only have one record with 1

   ```
   SELECT
       e.empid,
       COALESCE(OneAppoint.appointmentID, ZeroAppoint.appointmentID) appointmentID
   FROM
       employee e
       LEFT JOIN appointment ZeroAppoint
           INNER JOIN (
           SELECT
               max(a.appointmentid) appointmentid ,
           a.EmpID    
           FROM
               appointment a
           WHERE
               a.Visibility =0 

               ) maxZeroAppoint
           ON ZeroAppoint.appointmentid = maxZeroAppoint.appointmentid
       ON e.empID = ZeroAppoint.empID
       LEFT JOIN appointment OneAppoint
       ON e.empID = OneAppoint.empID 
           and OneAppoint.Visibility = 1
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
With SelectedAppointments AS
{
   SELECT * FROM Appointments WHERE Visibility <> 2 
}

SELECT  Employee.Id, < All columns of SelectedAppointments unless EmployeeId> 
   FROM Employee LEFT JOIN SelectedAppointments   
   on Employee.Id = SelectedAppointments.EmployeeId
```

Comment: Hmmmm sorry that i put the tag at sql server 2005, while i have sql 2000 in my message. doesn't really matter because i want it working on both versions. sorry for the mishap. I like these answers thanks as specially with the top 1. I forgot to mention one thing and i believe i got it working. If an employee has already got an appointment with visibility 1, it may no exists in the selection where he has an appointment 0 or 2.

Comment: I got something working: select max(a.id), a.empid from appointment a where a.visibility = 1 group by a.empid union select max(a.id), a.empid from appointment a where visibility = 0 and not exists (select * from appointment a1 where visibility = 1 and a.empid = a1.empid) group by a.empid ... it only selects those records which are visible and those records which are not visible.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from Employee as Emp
  left outer join
    (select top 1 *
     from Appointments
     where Visibility <> 2
     order by Visibility desc) as App
  on Emp.EmpID = App.EmpID
```